# Selenium Web driver outputs wrong row count of web table

Tags: java, web, selenium-webdriver, html-table, row

I am using selenium web driver to count the rows of a web table.  This is my code for that part:

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='z-listbox-body']/table/tbody/tr")); totalrows = rows.size();
```

It doesn't output the expected result. Can anyone tell me why?

Comment: What are the actual and expected results? Could you post a snippet of the  page source that illustrates what it's supposed to be finding?

Comment: What is actual/expected result? Dom example please.

Comment: This code outputs 1 while I am expecting 76 rows. I think it only counts the first row. I also tried this code: List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.tagName("tr")); but this outputs 17 rows instead of 76.

Comment: By the way, this is the xpath of the first <tr> tag: /html/body/div/div/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody[1]/tr[1] Is it because I accessed the xpath wrongly?

Answer (score 0):

You should select the `<tbody>` first, store the element, find all `<tr>`s in the current element and then you should get your value by getting the length of the list obtained:

```
WebElement tbody = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='z-listbox-body']/table/tbody"));
List<WebElement> rows = tbody.findElements(By.xpath("tr"));
totalrows = rows.size();
```

Sorry if I did something wrong, but I'm using Selenium with Python, never with Java.

This is the Python code that is working:

```
tbody = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='z-listbox-
body']/table/tbody")
rows = tbody.find_elements_by_xpath("tr")
totalrows = len(rows)
```

Note that when I'm selecting the tbody I am doing `find_element_by_xpath` so will get only the first element and store it in a normal variable and when selecting the rows I am doing `find_elments_by_xpath` so will get a list of elements.